# how to upload compressd file in php

Tags: php, file-upload

I have uploaded 3 files:

1. Provisioning file
2. plist file
3. Ipa file

Provisioning file & plist file are uploaded but Ipa file is not uploaded.

How to upload the above files?

Comment: show us your code and then you can receive help

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How big is the `lpa` file?  Assuming that lpa file is large, it could be a configuration problem.  If you want accurate responses, post your code and post any relevant error messages.  Failing that, search stackoverflow.com:

- [How to upload multiple large files in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730712/how-to-upload-multiple-large-files-in-php)

Here is a good place to start ... assuming again, that the file is too large given that the otehr two were successful.